# How to check if a solar panel has a built-in blocking diode?

Tags: diodes, solar-cell

Is it as simple as connecting a voltage to a fully shaded solar panel and checking if any current flows into it? For example using a battery with a resistor in series to limit the current. Or does the voltage have to be near the rated voltage of the panel for any current to flow into it?

Is there some other way to do it?

Just to be clear, this post is about blocking diodes, not bypass diodes.

Answer (score 1):

If the panel is in the dark and you force its voltage to its nominal open circuit voltage, it should draw something like its nominal short circuit current if there is no blocking diode. If there is a blocking diode, it should draw much less.

Answer (score 0):

Put a meter in diode mode and check and see if you measure a diode in one direction but not the other polarity. One polairty should measure a diode voltage, the other direction should measure open.

Comment: I agree that in theory this should work fine. But have you tried it yourself?